# Embedding of a CW-complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I have to prove that a **finite** CW-complex of the type $\vee_kS^1_k\cup\lbrace e^2_j\rbrace_{j=1} ^l$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$. 
Can you help me?

Comment: Might help: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19618/when-does-a-cw-complex-of-dimension-2-embedd-in-r4

Comment: Thanks for the link of the topic, but it doesn't help me! xD

Comment: But isn't that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes but there isn't a direct proof of the fact...

Comment: I'd say there is no proof at all there, only a reference to Stallings' paper. My suggestion is to read Stallings' paper and see if you can use his arguments.